# unable to insert when the input month is august in sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, oracle11g, sqlplus

I have a table which have a field with date data type. Whenever I try to insert a record which month is august, sqlplus give an error

```
insert into hcheckin values ('T00003','C00003',to_date('11-AUG-2006'),'0800');
```

and this is the error message:

```
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

But when I input this record :

```
insert into hcheckin values ('T00001','C00001',to_date('08-JUN-2006'),'0900');
```

there is no error. I tried other months too. It only gets an error when I insert a data with AUG for the month.

Please help

Comment: Is there a trigger on the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rely on the default date format, but specify it explicitly:

```
INSERT INTO hcheckin 
VALUES ('T00003', 'C00003', TO_DATE('11-AUG-2006', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), '0800');
```

As per @a_horse_with_no_name's comment, a safer approach would be to use numbers instead of month names (or shorthands thereof):

```
INSERT INTO hcheckin 
VALUES ('T00003', 'C00003', TO_DATE('11-08-2006', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), '0800');
```

Comment: This still isn't 100% fail-safe. With different language settings this can still fail (because it's not always `AUG`). It's safer to use numbers instead of localized month names

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name good point - I added this caveat to my answer.